# How to set div id dynamically?

Tags: angularjs, haml

I need to set the id in template dynamically using scope.$id ?

I tried this:

```
%div{ id: "holder{{ $id }}" }
```

But that does not work, I wonder how would it be done in haml?

Comment: $scope.id | id: "holder{{ id }}"

Comment: can you please write it as haml?

Comment: %div{:id => "holder{{id}}"}

Comment: the result is: <div id='holder{{id}}'></div> , id was not substituted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [HTML to HAML Converter](http://htmltohaml.com/)

In your Angular Controller you want `$scope.id = 1`

Then according to HAML you want `%div{:id => "holder{{id}}"}`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign id in your HTML snippet. Find below how it will work.

In your controller, please assign a variable in your controller's scope. like

```
$scope.id = 'my-id-2'; //for example
```

And in your HTML snippet, it should be

```
<div id="{{id}}"></div>
```

Please make sure you've initialized your `app` and `controller`.

Comment: Thanks buy I need to haml version of it